# How to change guide created GUI figure window title name?

Tags: matlab, window, title

Does anyone know a way to change the window title name on my guide created GUI figure? I created an application for my company and I was able to change the window figure icon using the following code:

```
javaFrame = get(hObject,'JavaFrame');
javaFrame.setFigureIcon(javax.swing.ImageIcon('RTI_Water_DB_Window_Icon.png'));
```

Now I would like to be able to also change the gui figure window title.

I tried:

```
javaFrame.setTitle('Water Quality Data Base');
```

However this did not work with the following error:

```
No appropriate method, property, or field setTitle for class
com.mathworks.hg.peer.HG1FigurePeer.

Error in water_Quality_DB>water_Quality_DB_OpeningFcn (line86)
javaFrame.setTitle('Water Quality Data Base');

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 221)
feval(gui_State.gui_OpeningFcn, gui_hFigure, [],
guidata(gui_hFigure), varargin{:});

Error in water_Quality_DB (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
```

I do not want to do a File > Save as in guide to rename the .m and .fig files because I specifically want the title to be 'Water Quality Data Base' and it is not possible to rename a file using a string with spaces. I do not want to use underscores.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want to do?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

If it helps anyone, I am getting closer to the answer because I was able to change the window figure title of the main matlab command window by using:

```
jDesktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
jDesktop.getMainFrame.setTitle('my new title');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the title of a figure window in MATLAB by setting its `Name` property. There should be no need for you to use Java.

To set this within a GUIDE-created GUI, open the GUI in GUIDE, right-click the background, select Property Inspector, scroll down to `Name`, and set the name.

By the way, although it's fine for you to set the text on the figure title, what you're doing when you change the icon on the window is explicitly prohibited by the MATLAB license:

[You may not...]

> 4.6. alter, remove, or obscure any copyright, trade secret, patent, 
>          trademark, logo, proprietary and/or other legal notices on or in copies
>          of the Programs;

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention, I did not realize it was prohibited even for a figure window, but I guess when they say "any" they really mean "ANY".   Thank you for the solution, I thought I had already tried that method but apparently I never pressed save. Thank you very much, it worked!